# Using keyboard event in web page containing JApplet

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I'm having problems listening to keyboard events in my web page that contains an JApplet.

Half of the area of web page is occupied by an JApplet.  The other half is HTML.

I define my javascript event handlers like this:

```
function keyPressedTest(){
    alert("key pressed!!!");
}

function initListener(){
   document.onkeypress = keyPressedTest;
}
```

The Javascript keyboard listener works fine when I click on the HTML part of the page.  The problem is that when I click on the Applet, the javascript listener is not called on keypressed.

I also tried using jQuery, but same problem.

Anyone knows why the javascript listener is not called when I click on the JApplet and press a key?  Is there a way to configure the javascript listener for both HTML and JApplet? Or intercept the keypressed event at a higher level?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume the "Applet" is something like a flash object?

Comment: Hm, different technology, same answer:
As far as I know, you can't catch mouse events from embedded applets like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to Cerbrus I found out that keyboard events are not propagated between Applet and HTML code, like he says they are different technologies. I guess this is also security thing so other objects won't act as key logger and steal your passwords.

What I ended up doing is grabbing keyboard events from Java Applet and forwarding them to Javascript code.